# How to distinguish between successful and unsuccessful loading of the html5 media element?

Tags: javascript, mediaelement.js, media-source

There is a sequence of events that are triggered when audio is being loaded:

1. loadstart
2. durationchange
   ...
3. canplaythrough

But if something goes wrong then only 1st event `loadstart` is fired.

The problem is that I cannot distinguish between successful and unsuccessful cases (for example when audio file is not found), because from `loadstart` event I cannot get any information whether the loading succeeded or not and no events are fired later in failed scenario.

Our JavaScript is GWT-generated.

Please note that I am much more backend than frontend developer so I can miss something evident.

Comment: `Our JavaScript is GWT-generated`  ?? what does it mean, it is  a private library ?

Comment: @MisterJojo Google Web Toolkit, or GWT Web Toolkit, is an open-source set of tools that allows web developers to create and maintain complex JavaScript front-end applications in Java.

Comment: All events that you mentioned (loadstart , durationchange, canplaythrough) are standard events that are available for an audio tag. You should be able to set a listener for the "error" event (see more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/error_event) - this event will be fired if something goes wrong.

Comment: @Telary I did set a listener to "error" event, but it is not fired in problem scenarios

Comment: @EgorErofeev what about other "problems" events? What happens if you add the following events: waiting, suspend, stalled, emptied, abort? I would add them and see if any of them will be fired.

Comment: @Telary, I tried to add stalled/emptied event but no one of them has been fired. Also, I cannot use timeout solutions because loading file can be rather huge and it cannot be known whether it is still being loaded or suspended